# Why does iteritems() function in python retrieves the key-value pair in random order?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
>>> basket = {'fruit' : 'apple','veg' : 'potato', 'grain' : 'rice', 'liquor' : 'wine'}
>>> for k,v in basket.iteritems():
...     print k,v
... 
veg potato
liquor wine
fruit apple
grain rice
>>>
```

As can be seen from the above example, the key-value pair are not printed from left to right or from right to left.

To get a sorted result, I used

```
>>> basket = {'fruit' : 'apple','veg' : 'potato', 'grain' : 'rice', 'liquor' : 'wine'}
>>> for k,v in sorted(basket.iteritems()):
...     print k,v
... 
fruit apple
grain rice
liquor wine
veg potato
>>>
```

When I try to get the indices of the key-value pairs, I get

```
>>> basket = {'fruit' : 'apple','veg' : 'potato', 'grain' : 'rice', 'liquor' : 'wine'}
>>> for k,v in enumerate(basket.iteritems()):
...     print k,v
... 
0 ('veg', 'potato')
1 ('liquor', 'wine')
2 ('fruit', 'apple')
3 ('grain', 'rice')
>>>
```

Why does this happen? How can I print the key-value pairs as it appears in the dictionary definition, from left to right?

Comment: Dictionaries have no ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've ever made a hash table, you know that order is not necessary to store.

In fact, it's extra work.

If you want to keep the order of inserted items, you can use [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), which does just that.